# Connecting Java application to a database on a remote server

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am developing a Java application that needs a database. I know how to connect my application to a database that is stored in my local hard disk, but I need help to connect to a remote database.

```
    String host="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Test";

    Connection con=null;

    String uname="admins";

    String pass="admins";


    try {
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(host, uname, pass);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    }
```

The above code allows me to connect to a local database. What changes should I apply to connect to a database that is stored in a remote server?

Comment: in place of localhost enter the remote server's IP

Comment: Generally when asking questions: provide us with some more information on what you tried and what didn't work. Illustrate that you put effort into resolving your question by yourself.

Comment: Sharma has the right idea, so I will expand on his comment.  You need to make sure the remote database accepts connections over a network, rather than just localhost.  Make sure you can physically connect via a console/terminal/command prompt first, and then change your java code to point to the remote IP

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for Derby JDBC database connection URL for the network client driver:

```
jdbc:derby://server[:port]/databaseName[;attribute=value]*
```

By defaultthe port is `1527` if omitted. suppose the user abc with password xyz wants to connect to the remote database remotedb on the server dbserver, use the following URL:

```
jdbc:derby://dbserver/remotedb;user=abc;password=xyz
```

One more thing as Russell Uhl said in his comment first make sure the remote server accepts connection